# Как обработать ошибку в ajax запросе (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть код

```
     $.ajax({
        url:     "action.php", 
        type:     "POST", 
        dataType: "html", 
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(), 
        success: function(response) { 
//Данные отправлены успешно            
        },
        error: function(response) { 
//Данные НЕ отправлены
}
```

**Вопрос:** Что должен вернуть обработчик, чтобы сработала функция в error?

Comment: Вернуть status code в интервалах Клиентские ошибки 400 - 499
Серверные ошибки 500 - 599

Comment: `header('HTTP/1.0 404 not found');` 
Точно. Спасибо. Оформите это как ответ - отмечу как решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вернуть ответ с сервера. Status code

- Клиентские ошибки 400 - 499
- Серверные ошибки 500 - 599